# Customizing AutoFixture to create specific type

Tags: c#, autofixture

I want to create customization for NLog's LogLevel type. Instances can be created by FromOrdinal static method.

I want to restrict the ordinals used to create to the range (0..5).
Please mind, that I don't want to customize the entire fixture with the generator (as other integers might be bigger).

Here's the piece of code that I tried to use:

```
class NLogCustomization : ICustomization
    {
        public void Customize(IFixture fixture)
        {
            fixture.Customize<NLog.LogLevel>(
                c => c.FromFactory(() =>
                    {
                        var ordinal = this.nlogOrdinalLevelFactory.Create<int>(); //Throws invalid cast exception
                        return NLog.LogLevel.FromOrdinal((int)ordinal);
                    }));
        }

        private readonly ISpecimenBuilder nlogOrdinalLevelFactory = new RandomNumericSequenceGenerator(0,5);
    }
```

Unfortunately the code above throws InvalidCastException.
What am I doing wrong in here?

I'm using version 3.19.1.

Answer (score 1):

To consume the [RandomNumericSequenceGenerator](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/blob/master/Src/AutoFixture/RandomNumericSequenceGenerator.cs) and any other `ISpecimenBuilder` directly, use the [ISpecimenBuilder](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/blob/master/Src/AutoFixture/Kernel/ISpecimenBuilder.cs) interface:

```
object Create(object request, ISpecimenContext context);
```

In this example, instead of `Create<T>` do:

```
fixture.Customize<LogLevel>(c => c.FromFactory(() =>
{
    var ordinal = this.nlogOrdinalLevelFactory
        .Create(typeof(int), new SpecimenContext(fixture));

    return NLog.LogLevel.FromOrdinal((int)ordinal);
}));
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it. Why are those extension methods (e.g. Create) defined on an interface even though you shouldn't call them on anything but Fixture? Seems a bit counterinuitive...